# nodejs me tira un mensaje

Tags: nodejs

mi pregunta es acerca de que me sale este mensaje en la consola de node y no se a que se debe alguien me podría explicar?

> There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
>   This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
>   Use equal casing. Compare these module identifier.

Comment: Problemas con los nombres que has asignado a los módulos que invocas, considera editar y agregar el script involucrado

Comment: lo intentare gracias